# Distorted sound when feeding data to jack - .wav binary data into digital signals?

Tags: c++, jack

After a bit of troubleshooting I realized ( at least I'm pretty sure ) I have been feeding the wrong kind of values to sound ports via the JackAudio library.

This is the callback function that is currently working but producing incredibly distorted sounds.

I suspect I have to turn my binary ( then later converted to decimal ) data into a `float` signal between -1 to 1.

How can I do the latter?

Right now I'm feeding it a 16-bit wave music file. Each sample is of size `short`.

```
static int Process( jack_nframes_t nframes, void * arg )
    {

        SamplerClass * SamplerPtr = ( SamplerClass * ) arg;

        jack_default_audio_sample_t * LeftChannel, * RightChannel;

        LeftChannel = ( jack_default_audio_sample_t * ) jack_port_get_buffer( LeftChannelOutputPort, nframes );

        RightChannel = ( jack_default_audio_sample_t * ) jack_port_get_buffer( RightChannelOutputPort, nframes );

        for( unsigned int i = 0; i<nframes; i++)
        {
            LeftChannel[i] = SamplerPtr->SoundFile->getSoundDataRef().at( SamplerPtr->SamplePosition ) ;
            RightChannel[i] = SamplerPtr->SoundFile->getSoundDataRef().at( SamplerPtr->SamplePosition + 1;

            SamplerPtr->SamplePosition = SamplerPtr->SamplePosition + 2;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

`getSoundDataRef()` returns a `vector<short>` and I get the sample position via `vector::at`.

I'm keeping track of the sample position from a public int variable via `SamplePtr->SamplePosition`;

Here's debug output of the data format that's inside the vector for a 16-bit 41000Hz stereo wave sample. So it seems the data assigned to the channels is correct.

```
[INFO] [ 18:48:50.492] 288756 vec index RCh >1844
[INFO] [ 18:48:50.492] 288757 vec index LCh >1401
[INFO] [ 18:48:50.492] 288758 vec index RCh >-1251
```

Comment: How about you store the actual data you process, and compare that with the data you expect (you can do this by playing some pre-recorded WAV file out through the same sound-card that you are recording on)

Comment: Are you processing audio from an input jack, or sending pre-recorded audio (which you know is NOT distorted) to an output jack?  If the former.....  Are you connecting a line-level audio source into a microphone input? Or are you overdriving a line-level input with a headphone output that's cranked up too high? If so, then your input port is "clipping" the signal (cutting off the top & bottom portions of the waveform), which is the cause of the distortion. Are you able to use the same audio source connected to the same audio jack, as input to a different program, without distortion?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I thought I mentioned it's a wav sample from an actual .wav file. So yes it's prerecorded. The same file sounds fine with VLC media player with the jack plugin.

Comment: @phonetagger I'm reading the data straight from a file, there's no sound processing involved just passing the data to the output.

Comment: So, when you compare the files from the original and what goes through your code, what is the difference? Any chance that you are for example amplifying too much so the sound clips?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I actually don't know how to retrieve the data that I sent from Jackaudio library. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Well the first thing to do would be to dump it just before it goes out - just write it to a file or something.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I think I'm on to something that seems to be kind of obvious that doesn't need debugging. Digital signals are between -1 and 1. My data is binary straight from a .wav file (that was then turned into decimal above). How can I turn decimal values into a digital waveform between -1 and 1?

Comment: Assuming your values are -32768..32767, you could do: `x = sample / 32767.0;` - that gives you a "close enough", I would think.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Oh my gosh how exciting, it WORKS! Could you post this as the answer please? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments discussion, the solution is to pass the CORRECT data format to teh Jackaudio library - in this case, the format is floating point in the range -1.0 - 1.0, where the original data is `short int`, so converting each sample with the formula `x = sample / 32767.0;` will give the desired result.

Comment: Yep, that did it. Pretty obvious answer but I'm not used to converting between so many formats. Thanks for helping me troubleshoot this! :D

Comment: I know you already answered but I hope you could help me with one last detail. Instead of looping how could I use `memcpy()` to directly copy the samples into the variables `LeftChannel/RightChannel` and not have to loop through every `nframe` to copy each individual sample?

Comment: If you have to convert each sample, you can't memcpy, because you need to do the conversion. If you wanted to do some inline assembler, it's possible you could do the conversion with SSE instructions, but it's a bit too long for a comment to explain how you do that. At 44KHz, I don't think it makes that much difference anyways.

Comment: Of course, STL probably has some clever functions you can use to copy a vector<short> into a vector<float> with just one line - but it will still require a conversion for each, so the overall work will be pretty much the same - just that it won't look that way in the code... :)

Comment: Actually, I can convert the data before storing it into the vector. I could do a vector<float> in the first place!

Comment: The thing is that I'd have to copy float values from a `<vector>` to `LeftChannel[i]` which is not a vector variable.

Comment: So use `memcpy(leftChannel, &v[0], size);`. `vector` is guaranteed to have contiguous storage for all elements.